# Attaching class as method

Tags: python

I discovered a slightly strange corner of Python I was hoping to get some help understanding.

Suppose I have a class `B` that I want to attach as a method for class `A`. I can do:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    print("a self is %s " % self)

class B:
  def __init__(self):
    print("b self is %s " % self)

setattr(A, "B", B)

a = A()
a.B()
```

When I call `a.B()`, in the `B.__init__` I get a `self` object for a new B instance.

Now suppose I want to capture the actual value of the `a` instance in the `B` constructor. I figured out you can do it with a wrapper function:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    print("a self is %s " % self)

class B:
  def __init__(self, a_instance):
    print("b self is %s a_instance is %s " % (self, a_instance))

def _(*args, **kwargs):
  return B(*args, **kwargs)
setattr(A, "B", _)

a = A()
a.B()
```

With the wrapper function, `a_instance` will be passed in with the actual instance reference of the `a` object.

This is helpful to know, my problem is I really don't understand what's going on. I was hoping someone could provide a clearer explanation of why, if I just `setattr` with the B class, I do not get the `a` instance, but if I `setattr` with a wrapper around the B class that just calls it, I then do get the `a` instance.

Comment: It's because functions are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: By the way, `setattr(A, 'B', B)` is a really weird way of writing `A.B = B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FunctionType` implements [`__get__`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) so that, when a function is called on an instance of a class on which its defined (i.e. as a `bound_method`), the owning instance (`A` here) is passed to it as the first argument. `type` doesn't have that `__get__`, so its instances, like `B` in your example, don't receive the owning instance when called.

`@staticmethod` is nearly always a mistake in real code, but you could use it on your function to emulate the behavior of the class here for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Quick test is indicating that `functools.partial(B)` does not successfully replace the wrapper function.

Comment: Besides that, I think this is the correct answer and will likely accept it but will give some time for others.

Comment: Edited, `partial` doesn't have `__get__`.